# Getting data from a row in HTML 5 table

Tags: php, html

I have a two dimensional array in php that I iterate through and return each element as a row in a HTML table - with the last column in the table being a button.

When the button is clicked, I need to store the details of that particular row in seperate variables, but struggling to get anything to work.

Any help appreciated !

```
for($i=0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++)
       {
            echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$resultsArray[$i][0]."</td>"; //NAME
                    echo "<td>" . $resultsArray[$i][1] . "</td>"; //LOCATION 
                    echo "<td>" . $resultsArray[$i][2] ."</td>"; // DISTRICT
                    echo "<td>" ."approx ".$resultsArray[$i][3]  . " miles" ."</td>"; // DISTANCE               
                    echo "<td>" . "#".$resultsArray[$i][5]. "</td>"; //REFERENCE NUMBER
                    echo "<td>". "<button>"."Get Details"."</button>"."<td>"; // BUTTON
            echo "</tr>";               
        }
```

Comment: You have to use javascript for do the job, you can do it with php but will be to hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the details for that particular row u need to make changes in the button code from

```
echo "<td>". "<button>"."Get Details"."</button>"."<td>"; // BUTTON
```

to this

```
echo "<td>". "<button class='getrowdata'>"."Get Details"."</button>"."<td>"; // BUTTON
```

and then use the jquery to get the values from the parent node.and then write is something like this->

```
jQuery('.getrowdata').on('click', function() {
    var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    var $columns = $row.find('td');
    var values = "";
    jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) {
        values = values + 'td' + (i + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
        alert(values);
    });
    //console.log(values);
});
```